# Display area isn't showing up when java Swing program is run

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Ch5PA1 extends JFrame {

    private String[] courseDescription = new String[5];
    private JLabel courseLabel;
    private JButton closeProgram;
    private JTextArea displayArea;
    private Font largeFont;
    private ImageIcon computer;
    private JComboBox<String> coursesCombo;
    private JPanel p1, p2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        Ch5PA1 frame = new Ch5PA1();
        frame.setSize(700, 400);
        frame.setTitle("CIT Courses and Descriptions");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Ch5PA1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createIcon();
        createLabel();
        createTextArea();
        createCombo();
        createButton();
        createPanels();

        JComponent cp = (JComponent) getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 40));
        cp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        cp.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cp.add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void createIcon() {
        computer = new ImageIcon("computer.jpg");
    }

    public void createLabel() {
        courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course From the List", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        courseLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("computer.jpg"));
    }

    public void createTextArea() {
        displayArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        displayArea.setLineWrap(true);
        displayArea.setEditable(false);

        displayArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    public void createCombo() {
        coursesCombo = new JComboBox<String>();
        coursesCombo.addItem("CIT 110");
        coursesCombo.addItem("CIT 111");
        coursesCombo.addItem("CIT 149");
        coursesCombo.addItem("CIT 170");
        coursesCombo.addItem("CIT 249");

        coursesCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                setDisplay(coursesCombo.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });

        setDisplay(0);
    }

    public void createButton() {
        closeProgram = new JButton("Close Program");
        closeProgram.setFont(largeFont);
        closeProgram.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createPanels() {
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.add(coursesCombo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(closeProgram, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        p1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 40, 20, 40));

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 20, 40));
        p2.add(courseLabel);
        p2.add(displayArea);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        p2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 40, 20, 40));
    }

    public void createDescriptions() {
        for (int i = 0; i < courseDescription.length; i++) {
            courseDescription[i] = getDescription(i);
        }
    }

    public String getDescription(int i) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("text/description" + i + ".txt"));

            while (input.hasNext()) {
                result.append(input.nextLine() + '\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading file! Check name   and location of file.");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    public void setDisplay(int index) {
        displayArea.setText(getDescription(index));
    }
}
```

Comment: The component `cp`, which contains the `displayArea` is never added to anything

Comment: how do I do that? I'm confused right now., sorry. Every time I try to add cp I get an error. I thought that where I added the displayArea to the second panel would make it display when the program is run

Comment: sometimes people are in a bad mood, and they will behave nasty, and nothing you say can change that. just realize that it has nothing to do with you. that is the only reasonable way to deal with it. regarding questions on SO, you should stick to the minimal (so no: thank you, please, i need help, i am new, <personal history>, ...) out of respect of the reading time you would waste for people (even the nasty ones ;-) ).

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the frame? add(cp);

Answer (score 0):

The component `cp`, which contains the `displayArea` is never added to anything

```
public Ch5PA1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createIcon();
    createLabel();
    createTextArea();
    createCombo();
    createButton();
    createPanels();

    JComponent cp = (JComponent) getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 40));
    cp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    cp.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    cp.add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cp.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Not added to anything?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

- Two items are added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` location of `JFrame`s content pane. One is a `JScrollPane` with `displayArea` and other one is `p2`.
- `p2` is already set to add `displayArea` in method `createPanels`.

### Solution

Remove line `cp.add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);` or if `p2` is not really needed, remove `p2` references and remove statement `cp.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);`.

### Output

[image]